# Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : ValueError: in user code:

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to work on Neural Networks with R. Keras and TensorFlow is installed. Below is the fit method which throws the error:

```
history \<- model %\>%
fit(
x = X_train,
y = y_train,
batch_size = 8,
epochs = 50,
verbose = 2,
validation_split = 0.2
)
```

This is the error that I'm getting from the console:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
ValueError: in user code:

\<...truncated...\>s/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1080, in train_step
y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/Users/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/Users/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 197, in assert_input_compatibility
raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Missing data for input "dense_39_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['VehPower', 'VehAge', 'DrivAge', 'BonusMalus', 'VehBrand_embedded', 'VehGas_encoded', 'Region_embedded', 'Area_encoded', 'Density']. Expected the following keys: ['dense_39_input']
```

Please see complete code below:

```
# Split data into train and test sets after pre-processing
   set.seed(123) 

   data_split <- initial_split(filtered_data_NN, prop = 0.7) 
   train_data <- training(data_split)
   test_data <- testing(data_split)

   nrow(train_data)
   nrow(test_data)

# Predictor variables
   X_train <- train_data[, c("VehPower", "VehAge", "DrivAge", "BonusMalus", 
                          "VehBrand_embedded", "VehGas_encoded", "Region_embedded",  "Area_encoded", "Density")]

   X_test <- test_data[, c("VehPower", "VehAge", "DrivAge", "BonusMalus", 
                        "VehBrand_embedded", "VehGas_encoded", "Region_embedded", "Area_encoded", "Density")]

# Target variables
  y_train <- train_data$ClaimNb
  y_test <- test_data$ClaimNb


# Create a simple feedforward neural network model
  model <- keras_model_sequential()


# Add input layer
  model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 20, activation = "relu", input_shape = 9) #there are 9 features


# Add output layer for count data
  model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "linear") #working on frequency data

# Define the optimizer (using the legacy optimizer due to the warning in M1 Mac)
  optimizer <- tf$keras$optimizers$legacy$Adam()

# Compile the model
  model$compile(
  loss = "poisson",
  optimizer = optimizer,
  metrics = 'accuracy'
)

# Print the summary of the model
  summary(model)


# Train the model and evaluate on validation data
  history <- model %>% 
  fit(
    x = X_train,
    y = y_train,
    batch_size = 8,
    epochs = 50,
    verbose = 2,
    validation_split = 0.2
  )
```

Other system info is given below:

```
> reticulate::py_config()
python:         /Users/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/bin/python
libpython:      /Users/ronypabraham/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/libpython3.9.dylib
pythonhome:     /Users/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow:/Users/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow
version:        3.9.16 (main, Aug 16 2023, 14:43:53)  [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)]
numpy:          /Users/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.24.3
tensorflow:     /Users/ronypabraham/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow

NOTE: Python version was forced by VIRTUAL_ENV


> tf_config()
TensorFlow v2.13.0 (~/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow)
Python v3.9 (~/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/bin/python)


> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] xgboost_1.7.5.1        TMB_1.9.5              keras_2.13.0.9000     
 [4] reticulate_1.31.0.9000 tensorflow_2.13.0      rsample_1.1.1         
 [7] magrittr_2.0.3         reshape2_1.4.4         e1071_1.7-13          
[10] AER_1.2-10             survival_3.4-0         sandwich_3.0-2        
[13] lmtest_0.9-40          zoo_1.8-12             car_3.1-1             
[16] carData_3.0-5          countreg_0.2-1         Formula_1.2-4         
[19] MASS_7.3-58.1          boot_1.3-28.1          rpart_4.1.19          
[22] caTools_1.18.2         pscl_1.5.5.1           ISLR_1.4              
[25] glmmTMB_1.1.7          lmerTest_3.1-3         lme4_1.1-31           
[28] Matrix_1.5-1           dplyr_1.1.2            caret_6.0-94          
[31] lattice_0.20-45        ggplot2_3.4.2          gbm_2.1.8.1           
[34] Metrics_0.1.4          tweedie_2.3.5         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-160         bitops_1.0-7         lubridate_1.9.0     
 [4] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1  tools_4.2.2          backports_1.4.1     
 [7] utf8_1.2.2           R6_2.5.1             colorspace_2.0-3    
[10] nnet_7.3-18          withr_2.5.0          tidyselect_1.2.0    
[13] compiler_4.2.2       cli_3.4.1            scales_1.2.1        
[16] checkmate_2.1.0      proxy_0.4-27         tfruns_1.5.1        
[19] stringr_1.5.0        digest_0.6.31        minqa_1.2.5         
[22] base64enc_0.1-3      smoof_1.6.0.3        pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[25] parallelly_1.32.1    rlang_1.1.1          rstudioapi_0.14     
[28] BBmisc_1.13          generics_0.1.3       jsonlite_1.8.4      
[31] ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 Rcpp_1.0.9           munsell_0.5.0       
[34] fansi_1.0.3          abind_1.4-5          lifecycle_1.0.3     
[37] furrr_0.3.1          whisker_0.4          stringi_1.7.8       
[40] pROC_1.18.0          plyr_1.8.8           recipes_1.0.3       
[43] grid_4.2.2           parallel_4.2.2       listenv_0.8.0       
[46] splines_4.2.2        zeallot_0.1.0        pillar_1.9.0        
[49] future.apply_1.10.0  codetools_0.2-18     stats4_4.2.2        
[52] fastmatch_1.1-3      glue_1.6.2           ParamHelpers_1.14.1 
[55] data.table_1.14.4    png_0.1-7            vctrs_0.6.3         
[58] nloptr_2.0.3         foreach_1.5.2        gtable_0.3.1        
[61] purrr_0.3.5          tidyr_1.2.1          future_1.29.0       
[64] gower_1.0.0          prodlim_2019.11.13   class_7.3-20        
[67] timeDate_4021.106    tibble_3.2.1         iterators_1.0.14    
[70] hardhat_1.2.0        lava_1.7.0           timechange_0.1.1    
[73] globals_0.16.2       ipred_0.9-13
```

Any idea what the error is about? Kindly help me if you have any expertise in this area.